# Finally the simplest code on the net to write text on image

Tags: php, image, text, wordpress

I'm newbie in PHP , i have a project to write text on image , I search all the net for free and simple function to write text on image and after 10 days seaching and trying codes I got this

it works 100% with any PHP script 
you need JustAnotherHand.ttf font and canvas.png in directory to work with you 
plus imagick installed on your server

I did it but i canoot make it automatically done with wordpress
so my quoestion is 
1- change 
`$text = "lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem";`
by wordpress post title
my trial was

```
$text = "<?php the_title(); ?>";
```

2-change file_put_contents('file33333333.png', $image);
by post_id in order to easily echo each image of each post 
my trial was

```
wp-content/uploads/2014/<?php the_ID(); ?>.png
```

3-echo final image link in each post
my trial was

```
echo '<img src="wp-content/uploads/2014/<?php the_ID(); ?>.png" alt="';the_time('F dS, Y');echo '" align="left" style="margin:0 2px 0 0" />';
```

Comment: Side-note, it's "lorem", not "loprem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try the getter function:

```
$text = get_the_title();
```

Instead of the "dump" function?

Comment: but what about post id?
wp-content/uploads/2014/<?php the_ID(); ?>.png

Comment: `get_the_ID`. I don't even use Wordpress, I just Googled "wordpress get ID".